# XML file not opening in Internet Explorer

Tags: xml, internet-explorer

I am not able to able XML files in my Internet Explorer 8. When i Try to open it, IE throws an error stating:

Cannot view XML input using style sheet.Please corect the error and try again.
System error: -2146697211.

But I am able to view the XML in notepad. Please help me with this...

Comment: what has this got to do with oracle

Answer (score 1):

the xml file is not a valid one.

notepad show you the text.
ie8 try to validate the xml.

use an xml editor to find the error's location and try to fix it.